# Search all sub directories for a value within an XML and return the sub directory name along with the value

Tags: grep

Example

Directory path: /this/dir/contains/

Sub directories:  sub1; sub2; sub3

Within every sub directory there's an xml:  hello.XML

*/this/dir/contains/sub1/hello.XML*

In hello.XML there's a string that looks like this:  Zipper="YYZ"

Note the value "YYZ" can be different in each hello.XML

Can I use grep to return the sub directory name and the "Zipper" value in every hello.XML

Comment: That’s an easy task that you should be able to to by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Use the option "**-R**" to **Recursively search subdirectories** listed.

```
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/anku/Documents/project
bash-3.2$ cat sub1/sub1.xml
Some line
Zipper="HELLO1"
some line
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ cat sub2/sub2.xml
Some line
Zipper="HELLO2"
some line
bash-3.2$ cat sub3/sub3.xml
Some line
Zipper="HELLO3"
some line
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ grep -Ri "Zipper" *
sub1/sub1.xml:Zipper="HELLO1"
sub2/sub2.xml:Zipper="HELLO2"
sub3/sub3.xml:Zipper="HELLO3"
bash-3.2$
```

Please add your efforts as well while asking.
good luck